# How do rats open a walnut?

Tags: behaviour, rodents

What techniques do rats use to open a walnut? What are the traces they leave in nature?

I have a book on traces that wild animals leave in nature, but it only explains squirrels (splitting the walnut in two halves, using their teeth as a lever) and mice (gnawing a hole into the hull of the nut). I am interested in the two common European species of rats, brown rat (Rattus norvegicus) and black rats (Rattus rattus).

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](https://www.smallpetjournal.com/can-rats-eat-nuts/) targeted at pet owners, it is implied that rats open nuts by gnawing on them (similar to mice, I presume). There don't seem to be scientific studies on the mechanics of how rats open walnuts. **However** [this interesting study](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/british-journal-of-nutrition/article/dosedependent-effects-of-walnuts-on-motor-and-cognitive-function-in-aged-rats/2E97D7C0EBA2A9FAFEE7E8FC45778E19) did find that consumption of walnuts improves brain function in aged rats, which is fascinating.

Based on this, I would expect the traces left behind in nature to be similar to those of mice, although the gnawed hole would potentially be larger given the relative [difference in tooth size](https://animals.mom.com/comparison-teeth-rats-mice-7208.html) between the two groups.